# Wirecloud Eclipse plugin error during setup

Tags: fiware-wirecloud

I'm trying to setup the Eclipse environment for wirecloud projects creation. 
When I try to create a new Wirecloud server I get 
Invalid Authorization Request bad_request
after I input the credentials in the embedded login window.
I used a dummy URL when creating the application on the Fiware Portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually means the callback URL provided for creating the application inside the IdM server (https://account.lab.fi-ware.org) is not the expected one. See the [user guide](https://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php?title=Application_Mashup_-_Wirecloud_-_User_and_Programmer_Guide#WireCloud_IDE) for more info.

For example, if you want to connect your IDE with the Mashup portal available at FIWARE Lab, you should use the following URL as callback URL: `https://mashup.lab.fi-ware.org/oauth2/default_redirect_uri`